# Check two empty cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to check if two cells are empty. I know how to check for one cell but I can't get to figure out how to check two separate cells. This is one of the ways I have tried. When I run it, it will only check for F17 but not for F12, if I switch the numbers it will check only for F12. I appreciate any help. Thank you

```
Sub Button11VerifyFilePathPresent_Click()
Dim rCell As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
Set rCell = Range("F17", "F12")

If IsEmpty(rCell) Then
    MsgBox "Please select the files" ' "Cell " & rCell.Address & " is empty."
End If

BeforeExit:
Set rCell = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & " Error in procedure CellCheck."
Resume BeforeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just do `If IsEmpty(Range("F17")) And IsEmpty(Range("F12")) Then`

Comment: Actually it worked, I forgot to change the range variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
If Range("F17") & Range("F12") = "" Then
```

If the concatenation is null, then they both must be null.